# Function won't return value

Tags: python, function, mapreduce, return

I have an assignment to code my own map function and I'm not sure why it's not returning any value. Here's the code below:

```
def mymap(func, lst):
    new_lst = []
    for items in lst:
        new_lst.append(func(items))
    return new_lst

mymap(abs, [3,-1, 4, -1, 5, -9])
```

It should return [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9], but when I run it, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Check your indentation. is this how your code is supposed to be indented? Copy paste your code over, and then select the code and press ctrl+k to format it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `print` in:

```
def mymap(func, lst):
    new_lst = []
    for items in lst:
        new_lst.append(func(items))
    return new_lst

print(mymap(abs, [3,-1, 4, -1, 5, -9]))
```

Outputs:

```
[3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]
```

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot.

Comment: @exc22 no problem